# How to scrape with table class name with R?

Tags: html, r, class, web-scraping, rvest

I am tryng to scrape several web pages, particulaty some tables in the pages.
But the problem is the places of tables change with respect to each page.
Here is my code.

```
url <- paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011%E2%80%9312_Welsh_Premier_League")
webpage <- read_html(url)
j<-webpage%>% html_node(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/table') %>%html_table(fill=T)
```

This code works fine, but I want to scrape the other seaons, too. The place of table changes in every season.
My question is I found that the table class that I want to scrape is named as "wikitable plainrowheaders", as below. I would like to know how to scrape with table class name.
How to scrape all tables with table class named as "wikitable plainrowheaders" in a wikipedia page?

```
<table class="wikitable plainrowheaders" style="text-align:center;font-size:100%;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the table class name, just change the corresponding xpath.

```
library(rvest)

url <- paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011%E2%80%9312_Welsh_Premier_League")

webpage <- read_html(url)

j <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes(xpath="//table[@class='wikitable plainrowheaders']") %>%
  html_table(fill=T)
```